# How to make two view animations run one by one?

Tags: iphone, ios, uianimation

I am to make "Guess match card" game, that is :there are 24 cards(UIImageView) in the windows with hide inside view shown surface, They a 12 groups number,you touch one, then it will be open show  inside,find if there has a same card opened, if not matched, two opened card will then hide.

Just this.

open card and hide card action used UIView animation. But now I have a problem.when I touched card, it then try to find if there has a match. But open card and close card action animation execute at same time. even I can't see what card content I see clear.

I want to open a card after I touch it, then (even wait for 0.5 second) close the opend not matched cards at same time. not open card and close card at same time. But in my code below I did open a card first,then compute, and close two opend card then.

```
@interface Card : UIImageView

@property BOOL expanded;
@property BOOL found;
@property (retain)NSString * nameTitle;
@property (retain) UIImage * expandedImage;

@end


//
//  Card.m
//  Guest card match
//
//  Created by  on 11-10-20.
//  Copyright 2011年 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Card.h"
#import "MainAppDelegate.h"

@implementation Card
@synthesize expanded;
@synthesize found;
@synthesize expandedImage;
@synthesize nameTitle;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cardface_48.png"];
        self.expanded = NO;
        self.found = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)openCard{
    NSLog(@"open card");
    if (self.expanded){return;}
    self.expanded = YES;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation1" context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self cache:YES];
    [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0)];
    [self setImage:self.expandedImage];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation1_open" context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
    [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}

- (void)closeCard{
    if (!self.expanded){return;}
    self.expanded = NO;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation1_close" context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];


    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self cache:YES];
    [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0)];
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardface_48.png"]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation2_close" context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];


    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
    [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    // Do what you want here 
    //NSLog(@"touchesBegan!"); 
    //[self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
} 

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 

    NSLog(@"card tag: %d", self.tag);
    if (self.expanded) {
        return;
    }

    [self openCard];
    for (NSInteger tagNumber=10001; tagNumber<10025; tagNumber++) {
        Card *card = (Card *)[self.superview viewWithTag:tagNumber];
        if (card.expanded && card.tag != self.tag && !card.found) {
            if ([card.nameTitle isEqualToString:self.nameTitle]) {// Found match!
                NSLog(@"Match!");
                [card setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                [self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                card.found = YES;
                self.found = YES;
            }else{
                NSLog(@"not Match!");
                [card closeCard];
                [self closeCard];

            }
        }else{
           [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
        }
    }


} 

@end
```

Update: I followed Kashiv, and this updated code:

```
- (void)openCard{
    NSLog(@"open card");
    if(cardAnimationIsActive) return;
    cardAnimationIsActive = YES;


    if (self.expanded){return;}
    self.expanded = YES;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{


        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation1" context:nil]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self cache:YES];
        [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0)];
        [self setImage:self.expandedImage];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation1_open" context:nil]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.2];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
        [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];



    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        cardAnimationIsActive = NO;
    }];




}

- (void)closeCard{

    if(cardAnimationIsActive) return;
    cardAnimationIsActive = YES;

    if (!self.expanded){return;}
    self.expanded = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^{
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation1_close" context:nil]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];


        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self cache:YES];
        [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0)];
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"android_48.png"]];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation2_close" context:nil]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.2];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];


        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
        [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        cardAnimationIsActive = NO;
    }];




}
```

But opencard and closecard animation still execute at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive this by using block-based animation:

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Then you can check if animation is still executing or is finished bu using `BOOL` iVar (e.g. `cardAnimationIsActive`).

Example:

```
- (void)openCard {
    if(cardAnimationIsActive) return;
    cardAnimationIsActive = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        --- your open animations ---
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        cardAnimationIsActive = NO;
    }];
}

- (void)closeCard {
    if(cardAnimationIsActive) return;
    cardAnimationIsActive = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        --- your close animations ---
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        cardAnimationIsActive = NO;
    }];
}
```

Comment: I have followed your guide, the opencard and closecard animation still execute at same time, not one by one.

Comment: May be the reason of prblem is :both in open card and close card animation there are more than one animations.

Comment: You can create complex animations by putting them in completion block.

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed you to create embed inside block, and at last inside compledtion block set  cardAnimationIsActive to NO;

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];
```

to delay all animations the proper time so they run in sequence.

Comment: I think you mean add this code in my "close card" animation. But I have tried, the open card and close card action still execute at same time.

Answer (score 0):

> [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
>        animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
>        completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];

You can create second animation in completion block.